# What equipment for hard core mode CoD BO

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I play CoD:Black Ops mostly in hard core mode. In hard core mode, most of the time, the minimap is not available. What equipments are recommended in this situation?

I typically carry claymore.

Also, I mostly use submachine or assault rifles and prefer slowly moving up instead of run and gun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claymore is pretty useful. C4 can also be useful in some modes and on some maps. I occasionally use a Jammer, since it disables Claymores and C4 (it's quite effective with Hacker Pro), and, in the event that the enemy has a Spy Plane up, it can be useful to disable approaching baddies' radars.

Answer (score 1):

Always move slowly and cautiously in hardcore mode.  When you're crossing wide open spaces though (such as the street in Havana) sprint.

As for weapons, I recommend the AK47 as its generally pretty accurate and packs a very heavy punch.  The Galil is also an excellent weapon.

If assault rifles aren't your style, some of my other favorites for hardcore include the M60, PM63, and WA2000.

I've not really found any perks that don't work well in hardcore mode, but usually I've got Hardline and Hardened.  These work pretty well for me.

Comment: +1 for Hardline. I run it with the spy-plane, and generally atleast another guy on my team runs the same too. Between the two of us, we ensure there's a spy-plane up almost continuously.

Answer (score 1):

I've played Hardcore for more than a year. And honestly, I require you to use the "Ninja" perk. Because hardcore doesn't have a map feature (unless one gets a spy plane, etc.) and when people have a headset, all they need is movement to hear you. And if you have Ninja pro, that really helps you to be unheard. Works best for me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't play much hardcore mode, but I would imagine that Motion Sensor would still help a lot because you can still look at the map in hardcore by just pushing start and looking at the full map.

However, I see **Claymores** being most useful in all game modes.